# regex for validating a phone number starting with +254

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to create a regex to match phone numbers starting with +254

examples of phone numbers 
    +254716370730

```
+254856798768

+254765432135
```

i have tried

```
preg_match('/^\\+254\\d{9}/,$phonenumber');
```

but doesn't seem to work, any assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try `preg_match("/^\\+254\\d{9}/","$phonenumber");` or `preg_match("/^\+254\d{9}/","$phonenumber");` may not need the quotes around the variable.

Comment: @Fred what is the meaning of `"\+"` ??

Comment: What do you mean `"\+"` ? @Brandin

Comment: @Fred-ii- within double quotes literal backslash must be escaped, or it should anyway. you may get lucky and get the same result but safer is "\\+" if you want a literal \ and + to be seen by the regex engine

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake; they should have been single quotes. @Brandin

Comment: @Benard it's upto you. Did you want to match the phone numbers which has exactly 9 digits after `254`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
preg_match('/^\+254\d{9}/', $phonenumber);
```

Comment: i think op wants to  match the phone numbers which has exactly 9 digits after `254`

Comment: @AvinashRaj If you want to make the comment why not post to the OP? Anyway the regex as posted seems to match from the beginning on purpose (using ^ anchor) e.g. `+999123456789` is a valid phone number but so is `+999123456789-foo` where foo is a local extension

Comment: @Brandin what AvinashRaj is saying is true i just want a phone number that starts with +254 and has exactly 9 digits following . i will appreciate the help

Comment: Yeah then in that case you had better put in the `$` anchor. e.g. `/^foo$/` matches exactly `"foo"`. `"foo1"` would fail and so would `" foo"` or `"foo "`.